# Inheriting in c++ with template classes error

Tags: c++, templates, inheritance

I´m new to c++. i´m getting an error "Symbol 'List' could not be resolved"
I´m working on eclipse i can´t figure out what is the problem...

List.h here is the declaration of the father class which is a generic class, which Vector
will inherit

```
#ifndef LIST_H_
#define LIST_H_

template <class E> class List {
protected:
    int size;

public:
    virtual ~List();
    virtual void add(E o) = 0;
    virtual E get(int index) = 0;
    int getSize();
};

template <class E> List<E>::~List() {
}

template <class E> int List<E>::getSize() {
    return size;
}

#endif /* LIST_H_ */
```

Vector.h Vector header file, which inherits from List, and it will implement the pure virtual methods of List
im getting the error, when i inherit from List, in the class declaration of Vector, "Symbol 'List' could not be resolved"

```
#include "List.h"
template <class E> class Vector: public List<E>{
private:
    class Node {
    public:
        E value;
        Node* next;
        Node(E value): value(value), next(0) {}
    };

    typedef Node* PNode;
    PNode first;

public:
    Vector();
    virtual ~Vector();
    void add(E o);
    E get(int index);
    virtual void add(E o);
    virtual E get(int index);
};
```

Comment: Templates and virtual methods don't mix well, unfortunately.

Comment: sorry, i forgot to put that, im getting the error, when i inherir from List, in the class declaration of Vector, "Symbol 'List' could not be resolved"

Comment: I wonder if your List.h isn't really being included, or if the wrong one is being included.  Try putting `template <class E> class List;` at the top of your Vector.h, and see if that changes the error message.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Quick search on google yelds that **Symbol 'List' could not be resolved** is not a compilation error, it's (stupid) eclipse is trying to rebuild a cross reference for you. Try a menu command Index->Rebuild.

Comment: It was eclipse, i`m trying it right now, in my own computer and it works just fine, thanks a lot for the help

Answer (score 0):

`virtual` specifiers are not part of overload resolution. You cannot use them to distinguish function signatures and thus the error: "cannot be overloaded".

For example:

```
void add(E o);
```

and

```
virtual void add(E o);
```

both have the same signature `Vector::*(int)`. They are not two different overloads.

Whatever you are trying to do, I suggest to take a step back and try to get fundamental concepts right first. It will safe you a lot of pain.